# Does the definition of open set coincides when the set is a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

When we work on a metric space, the concepts of open set is defined as

> A subset $A$ of the metric space (X,d) is called open iff $Int A = A$

And in topology books (see Munkress), a open set is defined as

> We say that a subset $U$ of $X$ is an open set of $X$ if $U$ belongs to the
>   collection $\tau$.

Apparently these two concepts are different with each other since in former case, $X$ is a set, and the latter case $X$ is a metric space.

**However, when $X$ is a metric space in the second case, is these definitions coincides ?**

**Secondly, when we work on a metric space $X$, does these two definitions are equivalent to each other ?**

Note that, I have started studying Topology 1 hour ago.

Comment: What is the collection $\tau$? If you define it to be the collection of subsets of X satisfying your first condition then they coincide

Comment: Why is this post tagged as a linear-algebra and vector-space question?

Comment: @laflaca The a habit mistake :), thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these define the same sets -- but for a decidedly boring reason: When $X$ is a metric space, the $\tau$ that appears in the second definiton is *defined to* consist of exactly those subsets of $X$ that satisfy the *first* definition.

Of course we could use all sorts of *other* $\tau$s that contain different sets, and then the definitions wouldn't coincide. But that would mean that we're ignoring the fact that $X$ is a metric space.

Remember that it is not $X$ itself but the *combination* of  $X$ and $\tau$ that make up a topological space -- just like $X$ is not *itself* a metric space until we decide on a distance function to go with it. When we have a distance function, we can always construct a $\tau$ such that the two concepts of "open" coincide.

Conversely when we have a $\tau$ there may be (but *is not always*) a distance function that leads to the same collection of open sets.

Answer (score 2):

A metric space $(X,d)$ induces a topological space $(X,\tau_d)$.

The collection $\tau_d\subseteq\wp(X)$ is actually defined as the the collection of subsets of $X$ that are open according to the definition of open on metric space $(X,d)$.

That guarantees that "open in metric space $(X,d)$" will be the same as "open in induced topological space $(X,\tau_d)$".

So you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: But what if we define another topology on X other than induced topology by the metric ?

Comment: If you equip $X$ with another topology $\tau$ then you can compare the topological spaces $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\tau_d)$. It might be that no metric $d'$ on $X$ exists with $\tau=\tau_{d'}$. You are stepping from metric spaces to a more general concept: topological spaces.